# Updating to Latest Spring Security - replacing Deprecated methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, deprecated

I'm trying to remove the deprecated methods below(csrf(), authorizeHttpRequests(), sessionManagement()). How can I write this piece of code instead?

Here's the code:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**", "/signup/", "/signin/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/search/", "/api/profile/", "/signout/").authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).build();
                //telling spring boot to use my own class JwtAuthFilter first before using your filter with username and password

    }
```

[IDE is generating errors for csrf(), authorizeHttpRequests(), sessionManagement()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F98wJ.png)

- can I just remove csrf? I have a frontend react app connecting with my Spring Boot backend.
- can I use authorizeRequests() instead of authorizeHttpRequests()
- what should I use instead sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your SecurityFilterChain Bean will look so:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(rQ -> {
           rQ.requestMatchers("/api/**", "/signup/", "/signin/").permitAll();
           rQ.requestMatchers("/api/search/", "/api/profile/", "/signout/").authenticated();
         });
    http.sessionManagement(sessionAuthenticationStrategy ->
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }
```

[Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Code seems more abstract and tidy. I'm using it and so far no issues.

Comment: @MohammadNayem don`t forget to read Migration Guide

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading it, thanks.